# I'm having some trouble to install the tscompdata package in my r

Tags: r, linux, installation

I'm trying to install the tscompdata package to R. This is a new one.
The installation is by the "devtools" package, using the following command:

> devtools::install_github("robjhyndman/tscompdata")

and the output is:

```
Downloading GitHub repo robjhyndman/tscompdata@master from URL
https://api.github.com/repos/robjhyndman/tscompdata/zipball/master
Installing tscompdata '/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ
--no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \   '/tmp/RtmpjrsG7p/devtools45d14034ea55/robjhyndman-tscompdata-0329cec' 
\   --library='/home/diego/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
--install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘tscompdata’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error : object ‘mstl’ is not exported by 'namespace:forecast' ERROR: lazy loading
failed for package ‘tscompdata’
* removing ‘/home/diego/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tscompdata’ Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

did someone face this problem too?

Comment: What version of R do you have? >= 3.4.2 is required

Comment: Check your version of `forecast`; [a recent commit](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/77360238b84d23ac435b59acbff281e68ac98f7d#diff-7347fe5a0f184f79ef064e92e3beb297) renamed `msstl` to `mstl`, so you likely have the older version.

Comment: Ohhh thanks. Update the forecast version works for me.